# Web scraping: duplicate class names mean I cannot specify data needed from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The classes on the website mean I cannot specify the sentences that I want to save.

This is the website: https://queue-times.com/parks/6/queue_times
I'm using python.  I would like to save the data in an ideal world like this:

```
name = soup.find('h1', class_="ride-name").text.strip()
queue = soup.find('span', class_="wait-time").text.strip()
reservation = soup.find('span', class_="reservation-time").text.strip()
```

( I made these class names up)

But I cannot work out how to use the classes to get what I want.  This is the ride names, the queue times and the availability of reservation slots.

This is what I have tried, but I have not been successful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://queue-times.com/parks/6/queue_times"

html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

rides = soup.find_all(class_="has-text-weight-normal")

output = []
for element in rides:
    output.append([element.get_text().strip()])


with open('input.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(output)

import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None).T.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

The output looks like this:

```
["A Pirate's Adventure ~ Treasures of the Seven Seas"]
['Jungle Cruise']
['â†³ No reservation slots currently available']
['Pirates of the Caribbean']
['â†³ Reservation slots available for 20:45']
['Swiss Family Treehouse']
['The Magic Carpets of Aladdin']
['â†³ Reservation slots available for 20:20']
```

In the end I am aiming for something like this:

| Ride | Queue Time | Reservation Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jungle Cruise | x mins | 00:00 |
| Pirates of the Caribbean | y mins | 00:00 |

If you know what to do next that would be appreciated.
I know this website has an API but the reservation slots are't included and I want that data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option :

```
import re
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://queue-times.com/parks/6/queue_times"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

data = defaultdict(list)
for ride in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "panel-block"}):
    rn = ride.find("span", {"class": "has-text-weight-normal"}).text.strip()
    qt_tag = ride.find("span", {"class": re.compile("has-text-dark-(.*)")})
    qt = qt_tag.text.strip() if qt_tag else None
    rt_tag = ride.find("span", {"class": "has-text-grey"})
    rt = rt_tag.text.strip() if rt_tag else None
    
    data["Ride"].append(rn) 
    data["Queue_Time"].append(qt)
    data["Reservation_Time"].append(rt)

df = (pd.DataFrame(data)
          .assign(Reservation_Time= lambda x: x["Reservation_Time"]
                      .str.extract(r"(\d{2}:\d{2})$", expand=False).shift(-1))
          .dropna(subset="Queue_Time").query("Queue_Time.str.contains('min')")
          .reset_index(drop=True)
     )
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                                          Ride Queue Time Reservation Time
0                                Jungle Cruise    70 mins              NaN
1                     Pirates of the Caribbean    30 mins            21:45
2                       Swiss Family Treehouse     5 mins             None
..                                         ...        ...              ...
30                       Tomorrowland Speedway    25 mins              NaN
31  Tomorrowland Transit Authority PeopleMover    20 mins             None
32          Walt Disney's Carousel of Progress     5 mins             None

[42 rows x 3 columns]
```